# How to set Ubuntu cluster?

Tags: server

So I have 4 regular desktop pc's that I would like to cluster together. The simplest way would be to set OS on it and connect them via gigabit Ethernet cable together. But, since I only have a limited number of network cards it is only possible to get one pc on the net and the rest plug into that one that can be visible from the net. This is cool but as soon as I need to get some new libraries this becomes a problem. So is there some tutorial how to set Ubuntu cluster. Furthermore is there a way that all my cpu's are visible from my front so that I don't need to set a grid job distributor?

Any tutorials or suggestions (regarding Ubuntu cluster solutions) are welcomed

Comment: Wow! Good question. I wish I knew the answer so I could answer your question.

Comment: I assume all the systems have a least 1 UTP or a wireless card? If so the easiest solution: get a router.